# Memory limit of LaserJet Printers: stick to the spec or okay to surpass memory size when choosing Memory Expansion modules?

Tags: memory, printing, printer

This is a technical question about what would happen if one adds a 512MB memory expansion module to the HP Color LaserJet CP5225, or any other recent current modern Laserjet, while the manual states that the maximum supported memory module size is 256mb.

The manual states that the maximum supported memory is 256mb DDR2 SO-DIMM.
What does supported mean in here?
Does it mean that the printer can only see 256mb extra?
Or does it mean that the printer will malfunction if more ram is inserted?

**In other words, will the printer see, recognise and use the first 256mb portion correctly, of an inserted 512mb expansion module?**

There are better faster cheaper 512mb ram modules from known brands, while the availability of 128mb and 256mb are dying and made by unknown expensive brands.
Hence the question: "must stick to 256mb spec" or "more is okay but will just not be used".

Interesting related background article: [Would upgrading RAM in a HP LaserJet printer improve its performance?](https://serverfault.com/questions/763495/would-upgrading-ram-in-a-hp-laserjet-printer-improve-its-performance)

Answer (score 0):

Putting a larger size memory module or one that is not compatible (mhz etc) will result in the printer not booting and will give a DIMM memory error.

Trust me, I have tried.